# INVALID_REQUEST_BODY Error calling ListStatusAsync using C# DocuSign SDK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am using C# DocuSign SDK.  I am simply trying to retrieve Envelopes, so using EnvelopesApi.ListStatusAsync. Like this:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopeApi = new EnvelopesApi(ApiClient.Configuration);
var options = new ListStatusOptions();
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
options.fromDate = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
var envelopesList = envelopeApi.ListStatusAsync(AccountId, null, options);
```

Response:

```
Error calling ListStatus: 
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_BODY",
    "message": "The request body is missing or improperly formatted."
}
```

Fiddler shows a 400.  I can see Access Token is included in the request (Bearer Authorization Header), so no issues there. Fiddler shows PUT request:

https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/[Account_ID_Guid]/envelopes/status?from_date=2019%2f12%2f14

Basically, this is code retrieved from: https://github.com/docusign/qs-csharp. Only difference is using ListStatusAsync instead of ListStatus.  Am I missing something related to Body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't quite match what the QuickStart example does. In the QS, the method used is ListStatusChanges, not ListStatus.

Try this to get a list of envelopes from the past 30 days:

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
var options = new EnvelopesApi.ListStatusChangesOptions();
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
options.fromDate = date.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");
var envelopesList = envelopesApi.ListStatusChanges(accountId, options);
var envelopesListFromAsync = envelopesApi.ListStatusChangesAsync(accountId, options);
```